# create model form from values of dropdown list in yii2

Tags: model, yii2, dropdown

I have a dropdownlist that listing the category's name from a table for example books table or projects table. each category has a special form for storing it to database and naturally each has different fields.
I need to get the selected name from the dropdown and create it model's form under itself.

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO is not a forum. You should describe your technical problem and post your code. Don't expect that other will program for you.

Comment: *Oh..! Wow..!!* But Dear, Where Is Your Tried Code. How Can We Assume Your Code.?

Comment: hello again
i am try to create a design pattern for this problem and i do not still coding for it.

i want know how do i implement design pattern for this problem.

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is only my code that listing cat's

```
<?php

       $dataCategory=ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
       echo $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList($dataCategory,
           ['prompt'=>'لطفا یک گروه را انتخاب نمائید']);
?>
```

and this code for get sub_category from database

```
<?php
$script=<<< JS
$('#cat').change(function(){
    var cat_id = $(this).val();

    $.get('index.php?r=site/getsubcat',{cat_id:cat_id},function(data){
        if(data != "no sub_category exist for this category!")
        {
            $('#sub_cat').fadeIn(500);
            $('#sub_cat').html(data);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#sub_cat').fadeOut(500);
            $('#sub_cat').html('');
        }
    });
});
$('#sub_cat').change(function(){
       alert($(this).val());
});
JS;

$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

this is my controller

```
public function actionGetsubgroup($cat_id)
{
    $subcat = SubCategory::find()
        ->where(['cat_id' => $cat_id])
        ->all();
    if(!empty($subcat)) {
        foreach ($subcat as $sub_category) {
            echo "<option value='$cat->id'>$cat->name</option>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "no sub_category exist for this category!";
    }
}
```

Comment: this code only for get sub_categories from table. after sub_category's dropdown was changed i should create it form depending on selected value for sub_category dropdown.